# How to iterate through regex matches with preg_match() and yield (PHP 5.5 generator syntax)?

Tags: php, regex, foreach, iterator

I want to iterate through the matches of a regex pattern.

I don't want to use `preg_match_all()` because it generates a temporary array of all matches I don't need. I also don't like to bloat things by building a full iterator class.

Luckily PHP 5.5 brings the nice [yield](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) syntax and I think in combination with `preg_match()` it should be possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

A simple example iterator that loops through all words of a string:

```
function wordIterator($str)
{
    $offset = 0;
    while ( preg_match('/\w+/', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
        $offset = $m[0][1] + strlen($m[0][0]);
        yield $m[0][0];
    }
}

foreach( wordIterator('Lorem ipsum dolor.') as $word) {
    echo $word.'<br>';
}
```